# Persentage bar graph in Spotfire

Tags: spotfire

after  filtered the data, I'd like to plot persentage bar graphs from that filtered based on total but when i chose my axis to be %of total everything turned out to be 100%. Dose anyone has any suggestion? Thanks in advance

Comment: Please add a code sample and / or screenshot of what you have or are trying to achieve. Stack Overflow should help you enhance your code or find solutions to concrete issues, but is not designed to build the solutions for you.

Answer (score 0):

One option you might consider is using a subset which will show total on one bar and the current filtering on the other like on the pic below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One more option to consider is to show shadows expressing unfiltered data.

[image]